# How you convert a std::string_view to a const char*?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

Compiling with gcc-7.1 with the flag `-std=c++17`, the following program raises an error:

```
#include <string_view>
void foo(const char* cstr) {}
void bar(std::string_view str){
    foo(str);
}
```

The error message is

```
In function 'void bar(std::string_view)':
error: cannot convert 'std::string_view {aka std::basic_string_view<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'void foo(const char*)'
 foo(str);
```

I'm surprised there is no  conversion to `const char*` because other libraries (abseil, bde), provide similar `string_view` classes which implicitly convert to `const char*`.

Comment: My mistake, [`std::std::basic_string_view::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) does not guarantee a null terminated string.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

A `std::string_view` doesn't provide a conversion to a `const char*` because **it doesn't store a null-terminated string**. It stores a pointer to the first element, and the length of the string, basically. That means that you cannot pass it to a function expecting a null-terminated string, like `foo` (how else are you going to get the size?) that expects a `const char*`, and so it was decided that it wasn't worth it.

If you know for sure that you have a null-terminated string in your view, you can use [`std::string_view::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data).

If you're not you should reconsider whether using a `std::string_view` in the first place is a good idea, since if you want a guaranteed null-terminated string `std::string` is what you want. For a one-liner you can use `std::string(object).c_str()` (**note**: the return value points to a *temporary* `std::string` instance that will get destroyed after the end of the expression!).

Comment: The explanation for why std::string_view doesn't provide a conversion is great, but only offers a provisional answer to the question.

Comment: Your recommendation about `std::string(object).data()` is a bad one, because in most cases the data will point to unallocated storage.

Comment: @rems4e  An alarm went off for me as well when I saw `std::string(object).data()` recommended without  the important caveat that the returned pointer is to data inside the temporary std::string object, which lasts only til the end of the largest enclosing expression.

Comment: Please remove `std::string(object).data()` from the answer or provide an easily visible warning. The `std::string(object)` here gets deallocated, so the resulting C string is undefined. I've seen this snippet being pasted all over the internet and in various code bases. This answer has caused an immense amount of damage.

Answer (score 60):

Simply do a `std::string(string_view_object).c_str()` to get a guaranteed null-terminated temporary copy (and clean it up at the end of the line).

This is required because string view doesn't guarantee null termination.  You can have a view into the middle of a longer buffer, for example.

If this use case is expensive and you have proven it to be a bottleneck, you can write an augmented `string_view` that tracks if it is null terminated (basically, if it was constructed from a raw `char const*`).

Then you can write a helper type that takes this augmented `string_view` and either copies it to a `std::string` or stores the augmented `string_view` directly, and has an implicit cast-to-`char const*` that returns the properly null-terminated buffer.

Then use that augmented helper type everywhere in your code base instead of `string_view`, possibly augmenting string view interaction with std string as well to catch the cases where you have a view that goes to the end of the std string buffer.

But really, that is probably overkill.

A better approach is probably rewriting the APIs that take `const char*` to take `string_view`.

Comment: by " (and clean it up at the end of the line).", I can continue use the member of that Rvalue til the end of scope that `std::string(string_view_object).c_str()` sitting, right?

Comment: @sandthorn No, until the end of the full expression, not scope.

Comment: @sandthorn If you want the string to stick around, you'd maybe prefer `std::string TempVar(string_view_object);` then where you need it in scope, `TempVar.c_str()`.

Answer (score 11):

You can call `foo(std::string(str).c_str())`.

Answer (score -2):

using object.data() solved my problem with compiler error C2664

Comment: Are you sure you haven't introduced a bug? Please see the other answers.

Comment: for my case I needed a pointer to the beginning of the string_view , I was using begin() instead of data() , which resulted in error C2664, and then I chcanged that to data() instead
but not sure if that introduces a bug, can you please give more details?

Comment: It depends on *your* use case. OP's one is to pass an entire `string_view` to a function accepting *only* a `const char*`. Those functions *usually* expect **null-terminated** arrays of `char` and that isn't guaranteed by `std::string_view::data()`, unlike `std::string::data()` (since C++11).

Comment: You should not do that! `std::string_view` does not guarantee that string it posints to is null-terminated. Just do `static_cast<std::string>(object).c_str()`
Yes, temporary copy. But safe and with null-termination