# Is it legal to static_cast a string_view to a string

Tags: c++, static-cast, string-view

My question is motivated by this answer on stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48082010/5360439. To quote,

> Q: How you convert a `std::string_view` to a `const char*`?
>
> A: Simply do a `std::string(string_view_object).c_str()` to get a guaranteed null-terminated temporary copy (and clean it up at the end of the line).

Unfortunately, it constructs a new `string`. I am wondering if it is OK to simply do,

```
static_cast<string>(string_view_object).c_str()
```

Now, my question is:

1. Does this constructs a new string?
2. Is it guaranteed to return a null-terminated char sequence?

I have a small piece of code for demonstration. It seems to work fine. (See wandbox [results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PQvb0zFWM8OcTsyZ))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  std::string str{"0123456789"};
  std::string_view sv(str.c_str(), 5);

  std::cout << sv << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(sv) << std::endl;
  std::cout << strlen(static_cast<std::string>(sv).c_str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that also creates a temporary `string` object.  I don't know how you expect to get the contents placed next to a NUL character without having a copy.

Comment: `static_cast<T>(o)` is pretty much the same as `T(o)`.

Comment: Please don't add a verification that essentially answers your question after someone posted an answer. It invalidates that person's effort. If the question was answered to your satisfaction, accept that answer please. Or post another answer with your own solution. SO is a Q&A site. Questions belong at the question box, answers at the answer section.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I wasn't meant to invalidate efforts from other people.  I haven never answered my question before, so my first thought is to post my answer by editing the question. Thanks for explaining the rule to me.

Comment: No worries. I know no ill will was present. Also don't be afraid to answer your own questions if you figured something useful out for yourself and think others may benefit. It's [highly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in fact :)

Answer (score 14):

`static_cast<std::string>(sv)` is calling the `std::string::string` constructor that expects any type convertible to `std::string_view` ([more details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)). Therefore, yes, it's still creating a brand new `std::string` object, which in turn guarantees a null-terminated char sequence.

Comment: I'd phrase that as "yes and yes" (OP asked two questions).

Comment: A string is NOT null-terminated.
It's the c_str() function that adds the null at the end.

Comment: The internal state of `std::string` may not hold a null-terminated string, but its interface provides one, i.e., `data()` and `c_str()` are both guaranteed to return a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`.

Comment: @Triskeldeian `C++11` guarantees that the internal data is null-terminated (without calling any explicit functions.). That includes calls to `.data()` which did not include the null-terminator in `C++03` nor was `.data()` required to be contiguous (was fixed after 03). You can

Answer (score -3):

A simple way to check if `static_cast<std::string>(sv)` constructs a new string is to verify if it's able to change original string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  std::string str{"0123456789"};
  std::string_view sv = str;

  std::cout << sv << std::endl;
  static_cast<std::string>(sv)[0] = 'a';
  std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(sv) << std::endl;
}
```

`sv` remains unchanged, so it does creates a new string.

See results on [wandbox.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oWngHNSh6yQntcoh)

Comment: You have to be careful with that "try it and see" approach particularly when it comes to strings. For example `const char* s = "hello";` followed by a `const_cast` and an attempt to modify that string by array indexing *sometimes* works, but actually the behaviour is undefined. The best thing to do is to check the documentation.